# Do coherent wave sources need to produce waves of the same wavelength?

Tags: waves, coherence

I've been taught that in order for two sources to be coherent, they must produce waves with identical wave speed, wavelength and frequency. However, when I think about this more, I question whether this is actually true.

For sources to be coherent, they must produce waves with a constant phase difference. For this reason, their frequencies must be the same. However, because wave speed = frequency * wavelength, wave speed and wavelength are directly proportional. That means that two sources can share a frequency even if their wavelengths and wave speeds are different.

Is my explanation correct? If so, does anyone have any ideas why I've been taught incorrect information? If not, clearing up any misconceptions I have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The general meaning of "coherence" requires the 2 (or more) sources to have a fixed phase relationship.  That is of course impossible when the frequencies are different.

Now, if you look at the "beat pattern" of two sources each of which has a long coherence length (such as two strings on a guitar), there is a clear repetition of constructive -to-destructive output amplitude.  Even that pattern will disappear when one or both sources undergo random phase jumps (as is the case for lasers with short coherence lengths).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the second part of your answer. Are you saying that the only requirement for two sources to be coherent is that they must share a frequency?

Comment: @Beezo  Indirectly, yes.    They are coherent, but if their coherence length is very short (rapid phase jumps) you won't get a strong SNR in the interference pattern, because the pattern will shift laterally everytime a phase change occurs.

Answer (score -1):

If  you want two waves from different sources to produce a stable interference pattern within a given medium, they must have the same wavelength and a fixed phase difference.  If the two waves have the same wavelength in the same medium, then they also have the same speed and frequency.

Comment: True but I don't think this is the point of the question.

Comment: Mr. Beezo seems to suggesting that in a given medium, the frequency does not determine the wavelength.